# Changing shown values of table (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get the values from a database-table column displayed?

For example as a html form table? or clickable button?

I have a table with values like lessonid, studentid, answer and corrected by student.
Now I can save different answer to the database, Show the selected lessons from the table.
But I want to "pick" one of them an "correct" it and save the selected answer to table.

What is the best way to solve this? Very grateful if someone have time to help me a bit.

Comment: There are many frameworks to handle DB read/writing, so with decent display/input. Are you looking for a framework?

Comment: i think i should try to solve it without if its possible. It a part of a schould task. Any tip?

Comment: Ah well, perhaps you should break the problem into steps. You need to perform a few steps in order. If you list them out it should be come clearer.

Comment: ah, i think i understand a little. say if i have a query like this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM oppgave WHERE lessonid = '3' and correctedby = 'Value' OR correctedby IS NULL";
 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con); 
while ($nextrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "Studentid: " . $nextrow['studentid'] ;

Comment: What do i do after to make a update or insert? or am i thinking wrong?Thank you for wasting time on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the values from a databasetable collumn shown for example as a html form table?

If you can't use an existing framework, the best way to do this is probably the use of a foreach loop.

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Table Headers :)</th></tr>";
foreach ($lesson as $unit) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$unit['question']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Obviously, you could add many more columns in the same fashion.

> But i want to "pick" one of them an "correct" it and save answer to table.

Not sure I understand the question, but you could potentially have a dropdown box in a form at the bottom of the page that lists the answers. You could select the "correct" one and click the submit button, which would post the data and write it to MySQL.

```
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' name='action' value='answer'>
  <select>
    <option value='".$yourValueHere."'>".$yourLabelHere."</option>
    ...
  </select></form>";
```

You could then have a section of the script that only executes when action == "answer". The section could write the selected answer to the MySQL database.